Is there a way to determine if the n-th roots of a polynomial is a polynomial?
Context: I was solving this problem: $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1}}$$
I solved this question because I just knew that $(1+x+x^2)^2=x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1$ but this made me wonder is there is a way to know if the $n-$th root of a certain polynomial is a polynomial?

Given a polynomial how to determine $n$ where the $n-th$ root of this polynomial is a polynomial and how to determine the $n-$th root of this polynomial?
There is Taylor theorem or the extended binomial theorem that can find $(P(x))^{1/n}$ but this is not what I am looking for because

It only deals with two terms and the more terms that a polynomial have the more one needs to use the binomial theorem on each term which gets very ugly.
It gives an infinite series which doesn't tell if each the $n-$th root is a polynomial or not
Even if one can make simplifications on the  infinite series to conclude it is a polynomial finding suitable $n$ would need one to check all the cases from $2-m$ where $m$ is the degree of polynomial, which is not very effective.


I would plug in some small numbers of $x$. In your example, $P(x)= x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1$ we have $P(-2)= 9, P(-1)= 1, P(0)=1, P(1)=9$ so I suspect maybe it is a square of other polynomial.

There is a long-division-like algorithm for calcluating the square root of a number. This can be converted into an algorithm for calculating the square root of a polynomial, in a similar way that long division itself has been converted into an algorithm for polynomial division.

For perfect squares see How do we check if a polynomial is a perfect square? Some algorithms for perfect powers are reviewed in Giesbrecht-Roche, Detecting lacunary perfect powers and computing their roots.

The discriminant is zero if the polynomial has a repeated root; so if it is nonzero then the polynomial won't be a perfect power.

There is a multinomial theorem to address your point 1.  I'm not sure it really helps, though.

If I understand the question correctly, you are given a polynomial of degree $~m~$ and you are taking the $~n$-th root of this polynomial, where $~m,n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.$  One quick and dirty constraint is that $~n ~| ~m,~$ and it is necessary for the $~m~$ not necessarily distinct roots to actually consist of $~d~$ (not necessarily distinct) roots, where $~d~$ is some factor of $~n,~$ and where each of the $~d~$  roots is a repeated root that occurs $~\dfrac{m}{d}~$ times.  This way, you have that $~\dfrac{m}{d}~$ is a multiple of $~\dfrac{m}{n},~$ as required.

If $f(x)$ is a power of something, then $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have that something as a common divisor.  In your case,
$$  \gcd(x^4 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2x + 1, 4x^3+6x^2+6x+2) \\ = x^2 +  x + 1  \text{.}  $$
More generally, $f(x) = (p(x))^n$ implies $f'(x) = n(p(x))^{n-1}p'(x)$, so $(p(x))^{n-1}$ divides both $f$ and $f'$, therefore divides their greatest common divisor.
Note that this also applies to powers of non-polynomials.  $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sin^4(x) = 4 \sin^3(x)\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ divides both of these.  It can be tricky to define gcds for non-polynomials.  Your experience with trigonometric identities should suggest that the "immediately visible" common factors may appear, vary, and disappear as we manipulate the expressions.
If everything in sight is a polynomial, then the leading term of $f$ must be an $n^{\text{th}}$ power and so must the constant coefficient.  For your example $f$, the leading term requires $n \in \{1,2,4\}$ and the constant term doesn't restrict $n$.  The fact that the gcd in your example is not a cube and is not a constant tells us $n = 2$.  Though the constant coefficient doesn't restrict $n$, if $f$ has a polynomial $n^{\text{th}}$ root, the constant tells us that root's constant coefficient is an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$.
Let's see if we can cobble this into an algorithm.  (Not optimal.  Not efficient.  Probably not even particularly good.  But at least a procedure that works.)  We will discuss starting with a polynomial having, integer ($\Bbb{Z}$), rational ($\Bbb{Q}$), real ($\Bbb{R}$) or complex ($\Bbb{C}$) coefficients and target $n^{\text{th}}$ roots from the same list.  The indeterminate will be $x$ and the collections of polynomials will be denoted $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, $\Bbb{R}[x]$, and $\Bbb{C}[x]$, respectively.  We assume we have a polynomial $f(x)$ from one of these collections and we search for an $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $n \geq 1$ and a polynomial $p(x)$ from one of the collections such that $f(x) = (p(x))^n$.
For this discussion:

The phrase "$f(x)$ is a first power" means that $n$ can only be $1$ and $p(x)$ must be $f(x)$.
$A$ stands for "either $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$", since almost always these are treated together.  Similarly, $A[x]$ is used for the collection of polynomials with integer or rational coefficients.  (By Gauss's lemma, these are really equivalent factorizations possibly wearing two different hats.)
$B[x]$ stands for "either $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$" since almost always these are treated together.  Similarly, $B[x]$ is used for this collection of polynomials.
Whenever we write a polynomial as $\text{[coefficient]}x^{\text{[power]}} + \cdots$, the elided terms have lower degree than the power shown.  That is, we have written the leading term and suppressed the non-leading terms.

Let's start by maybe making $f$ a little simpler.  Then continue by inspecting the leading and trailing coefficients of $f$.  We finish off by applying calculus a few times.

If the leading term of $f$ is negative, factor a $-1$ from $f$ and proceed below with $-f$.  If we eventually find $-f = p^n$ and $n$ is odd then $f = (-p)^n$; otherwise, $f$ is a first power.

Inspect the leading term.  If searching for a $p(x) \in A[x]$, factor the coefficient.  $n$ must be a divisor of each power of a prime and the power of $x$.  If searching for $p(x) \in B[x]$, $n$ must be a divisor of the power of $x$.  (The coefficient does not constrain because in $B$, everything has whatever root(s) we might desire.)
Examples:

$f(x) = 32x^{10} + \cdots$: The leading term is $2^5 x^{10}$.  If we want $p(x) \in A[x]$, then $n \in \{1,5\} \cap \{1,2,5,10\} = \{1,5\}$, so $f$ is a first or fifth power.  If we want $p(x) \in B[x]$, then $n \in \{1,2,5,10\}$.
$f(x) = \frac{32}{81}x^{10} + \cdots$: The leading term is $\frac{2^5}{3^4} x^{10}$.  If we want $p(x) \in A[x]$, $n \in \{1,5\} \cap \{1, 2, 4\} \cap \{1,2,5,10\} = \{1\}$, so $f$ is a first power.  If we want $p(x) \in B[x]$, $n \in \{1,2,5,10\}$.
$f(x) = \sqrt{2} x^{11} + \cdots$:  The leading coefficient is not in $A$, so $p(x) \not \in A[x]$.  So we search for $p(x) \in B[x]$ and have $n \in \{1,11\}$.


If we seek $p(x) \in A[x]$, then also factor the constant coefficient, with sign.  For instance, if the constant coefficient is $1$, it has infinitely many factorizations: $1^k$ and $(-1)^{2k}$ for any $k \geq 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}$, leading to $n \geq 1$ in $\Bbb{Z}$.  We always insert $n = 1$ by hand.
Instead, if we seek $p(x) \in B[x]$, the constant coefficient does not constrain $n$; we have $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, $n \geq 1$.
Examples, where we take $k$ to range over positive integers and we seek $p(x) \in A[x]$:

The constant coefficient is $4 = (-1)^{2k} 2^2$.  Then $n \in \left(2\Bbb{Z} \cap \{1,2\}\right) \cup\{1\} = \{1,2\}$.
The constant coefficient is $-4 = (-1)^{2k+1} 2^2$.  Then $n \in \left( (2\Bbb{Z} + 1) \cap \{1,2\} \right) \cup \{1\} = \{1\}$.


Take the intersection of the candidate $n$s from the leading coefficient and the candidate $n$s from the constant coefficient (if the constant actually leads to a constraint).  The set of surviving candidates form a lattice (of divisors of the largest candidate, ordered by "divides").
(The candidates from step 1 form a sublattice of the division lattice of the nonnegative integers.  The candidates from step 2 do also.  The intersection of two such lattices is another such lattice, so the set of survivors is such a sublattice.)
Let $N$ be the number of surviving candidates, sort the surviving candidates, and label them in increasing order $$  n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_{N}  \text{.}  $$
Example, where $60$ is the largest candidate:

image source
$N = 12$ and $n_1 = 1$, $n_2 = 2$, $\dots$, $n_7 = 10$, $\dots$, $n_{N} = 60$.

Suppose $f = p^n$ with $n > 1$ and degree of $p$ greater than one.  Let's see what we get for the leading term when we differentiate.  Let $p(x) = a x^d + \cdots$.  Then \begin{align*}
f(x) &= (p(x))^{n}  \\
&= (a x^d + \cdots)^{n}  \\
&= a^n x^{dn} + \cdots  \text{ and }  \\
f'(x) &= n (p(x))^{n-1} p'(x)  \\
&= n (a x^d + \cdots)^{n-1} (ad x^{d-1} + \cdots)  \\
&= n a^n x^{dn-1} + \cdots  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So the leading term of $f'$ divided by the leading term of $f$ is $n/x$.  If $f$ is not a power, then the leading term of $f'$ divided by the leading term of $f$ is still some constant over $x$, so again, this is a candidate $n$.
Either this candidate is on the list from step 3 or it is not.  If not, $f$ is a first power and we are done.  We've narrowed the list of possible powers to one.

Continuing the calculus from step 4 \begin{align*}
f''(x) &= n(n-1)(p(x))^{n-2}p'(x)^2 + n (p(x))^{n-1}p''(x)  \\
&= n(n-1)(ax^d + \cdots)^{n-2}(adx^{d-1}+\cdots)^2 + n(ax^d+\cdots)^{n-1}(ad(d-1)x^{d-2}+\cdots)  \\
&= a^n dn(dn -1)x^{dn-2} + \cdots
\end{align*}
So the leading term of $f''$ divided by the leading term of $f'$ is \begin{align*}
\frac{a^n dn(dn -1)x^{dn-2}}{n a^n x^{dn-1}} &= \frac{d(dn -1)}{x}
\end{align*}
This is, it's the degree of $p$ times one less than the degree of $f$ divided by $x$.  Since we start with knowledge of the degree of $f$, we can divide the number in the numerator by one less than this degree and get $d$.  Since $d$ has to be a positive integer, if the division has nonzero remainder, we discover $f$ is a first power and stop.
We can also check that the degree of $d$ times the one surviving candidate $n$ gives the degree of $f$.  (I think this second check might be redundant given the prior work, but haven't thought about it hard enough to be sure.)

At this point, we have one candidate $n$ for $f = p^n$.  Compute the polynomial GCD
$$  p(x) = \mathrm{gcd}\left( \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{n-1} f(x), f(x) \right)  \text{.}  $$
If $p$ is a constant polynomial, $f$ is a first power.  Otherwise, $f = p^n$.  (And remember to apply the conclusion of step 0 if you factored a $-1$ out of $f$ in that step.)
(One might say that computing the $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative is a lot of work, but it can be done in one step if one has a table of falling factorials, since $(\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x)^{n-1} ax^b = a(b)_{n-1}x^{b-(n-1)}$ if $b \geq n$ and zero otherwise.)



This will detect powers, but it's worth noting that it will also detect some non-powers, so once we find the GCD, we should investigate further to see if it actually has the right form to tell us that $f(x)$ is a perfect power. For example, if we have $f(x)=x^4+2x^3-2x-1$, then $f'(x)=4x^3+6x^2-2$, then $\gcd(f(x),f'(x)) = x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$, but $f(x)$ is not a power of $(x+1)^2$; rather, it is $(x+1)^3(x-1)$.

@MishaLavrov : I don't see that this differs from what I have written.  Although maybe you point out something that wasn't sufficiently explicit?

Yes - everything you wrote was correct and I'm not disagreeing with it, I just think this additional detail is worth mentioning.

What it detects is repeated facrors of any sort. If there are nonrepeated factors or factors are repeated different numbers of times, you generally don't have a pure power.

@MishaLavrov : Explicitness should be markedly increased.  (And I foresee new comments about polishing the described procedure.)

No there isn't a general way as far as I know. But there is one trick that I would like to tell you.

The polynomial you have $x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1$ 
is a symmetric polynomial so there is a possibility that it can be factorised. Let's check. You can use this trick for other symmetric polynomials.
Rewrite the whole expression as $\displaystyle x^2\left(x^2+2x+3+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$
Now you just have to club the appropriate terms. Rewrite this as
$\displaystyle x^2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+1\right)$
This is nothing but $\displaystyle x^2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)^2$
which certainly equals to $$(1+x+x^2)^2$$

You seem to be implying that all symmetric polynomials are factorizable, but that's definitely not true: consider $x^2+bx+1$ for any $|b|<2$.

Let me change that real quick

You mean, "let me change that non-real quick."

@PerAlexandersson It got changed, look at the edit history, now he says that "there is a possibility"

Suppose $x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1=(ax^2+bx+c)^2$. Then expanding the right side and equating like-power terms renders
$a^2=1$
$2ab=2$
$2ac+b^2=3$
$2bc=2$
$c^2=1$
The first equation has two roots $a\in\{1,-1\}$ and wlog we may take either one. Selecting $a=1$ then leads to the second equation giving $b=1$ and the third equation giving $c=1$. If these results satisfy both remaining equations then you may render
$x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1=(x^2+x+1)^2.$
A "real-life" example comes from Benjamin and Snyder's neusis construction of the regular hendecagon[1], which would be impossible with Euclidean tools plus an angle trisector alone. Their method ultimately depends on factoring a sextic polynomial
$u^6+4u^5+8u^4+12u^3+12u^2+8u+4,$
in which the degree is even, the constant term is a square and the coefficients add up to another square. To prove that this in fact is $(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)^2$, we expand and match:
$a^2=1\implies a=1$ (wlog)
$2ab=4\implies b=2$
$2ac+b^2=8\implies c=2$
$2(ad+bc)=12\implies d=2$
$2cb+c^2=12$
$2cd=8$
$d^2=4$
where the values of $a,b,c,d$ from the first four equations have to match the last three — which actually works, and thus as the authors put it, "a miracle occurs".
Reference

Benjamin, Elliot; Snyder, C. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society 156.3 (May 2014): 409-424.; https://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004113000753

